# Counting created lines on ancestor chapter level

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0, tei

I am working on a TEI document with a basic structure like this. There are several "mainText"-sections within a chapter; these sections have separate normalized and OCR versions of the actual text.

```
<div type="chapter">
    <div type="mainText">
        <div type="normalized">
             <p>HERE COMES <lb/> SOME TEXT<lb/></p>
        </div>
        <div type="OCR">
             <p>HERE COMES <lb/> SOME TEXT<lb/></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div type="mainText">
        <div type="normalized">
             <p>HERE COMES <lb/> SOME TEXT<lb/></p>
        </div>
        <div type="OCR">
             <p>HERE COMES <lb/> SOME TEXT<lb/></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With XSLT 2.0 I am right now trying to do the following steps, which already work:

- Replace mainText-divs inside every chapter with `<ab/>`
- Replace normalized and OCR version with elements `<reg/>` and `<orig/>`
- Replace `<p>` with a linegroup element `<lg>`
- Inside of linegroup, wrap every group ending with `<lb/>` in a line element `<l/>`

My problem is as follows: I want to assign a line number attribute to every line, but on chapter level, meaning: within a chapter there is a continuous line counter. See my current xsl templates which work with lines:

```
<!-- replace p with linegroup -->
    <xsl:template match="text//p">
        <xsl:choose>

            <!-- don't apply lingroup when there is nothing inside of p -->
            <xsl:when test="not(node())">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <lg>
                    <!-- make a group out of everything inside of p, ending with a linebreak -->
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="lb">

                        <!-- wrap a line aroung current group -->
                        <l>
                            <!-- for line element create number, if line is in mainText -->
                            <xsl:attribute name="n">
                                <xsl:number/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </l>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </lg>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- get rid if linebreak, as we don't need it anymore -->
    <xsl:template match="p//lb"/>
```

The output of this will create line numbers, but start counting within every mainText element. Would be glad about help.

Best,
Dominika

Comment: Well, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-number, that `xsl:number` element has several attributes like `from="div[@type = 'chapter']"` and `level="any"` that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- remove disallowed elements but keep its children -->
    <xsl:template match="div">
        <xsl:element name="{if(@type='mainText') then 'ab' else
            if(@type='normalized') then 'reg' else
            if(@type='OCR') then 'orig' else 'div'}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p//lb"/>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <lg>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(node())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>

                    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="lb">

                        <!-- wrap a line aroung current group -->
                        <l>
                            <!-- for line element create number, if line is in mainText -->
                            <xsl:attribute name="n">
                                <xsl:variable name="num">
                                <xsl:number count="lb" level="any"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:value-of select="if ($num = '') then 1 else number($num) + 1"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </l>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </lg>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See transformation at http://xsltransform.net/ei5Pwip